# I don't have the 'Merge Requests' tab on the left in gitlab. Where do I find it?

Tags: merge, request, gitlab, git-merge

I was following several YT videos as well as GitLab documentation to do a merge request. They all tell to go to the Merge requests tab on the left. I do not have such a tab there.
I have the following tabs on the left:

1)Project information
2)Repository
3)Deployments
4)Packages and Registries
5)Settings

How do I access merge requests tab on gitlab to create a new merge request?

Comment: Are you using gitlab.com or self-managed instance ?

Comment: I am using gitlab.com

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Settings > General` and make sure `Merge Requests` are enabled, with corrects rights :

[image: merge requests enabled]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Code > Merge Requests. You can pin this item so that it always appears at the top section of the tab group on the left.